# Друг и другой — корень один, значения разные

Tags: однокоренные-слова

"Друг" и "другой" — это ведь, как я понимаю, однокоренные слова, да? Но почему у них значения не просто разные, но где-то даже противоположные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значение местоимения-прилагательного другой развилось из сущ. друг.Был оборот ДРУГ ДРУГА, ДРУГ ДРУГУ и т.п. со знач."выручает, помогает". При таком употреблении во втором слове развилось значение признака "такой же", "иной", "не этот".Теперь это значение считается устаревшим. Слово имело вид ДРУГЫИ, по типу указательного слова, потом по аналогии с ИНОЙ оформилось как прилагательное -  ДРУГОЙ.Вот и получились противоположные значения.